# Javascript from processor - unable to debug issues

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form that I'm trying to submit and process with javascript using the code outlined below:

Form:

```
<form id="my_form_id" method="POST" action="my_processor_script.php">

        <input type="text" id="form_id_1" name="form_field_1">

        <input type="text" id="form_id_2" name="form_field_2">

        <input type="text" id="form_id_3" name="form_field_3">

<input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" name="save_settings_button" id="save_settings" value="Save Settings" />
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $form = $('form');
   $form.submit(function(){
      $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
            // do something here on success
            alert("Form Processed");
      },'json');
      return false;
   });
});    
</script>
```

Processor:

```
        <?php if (isset($post_data['save_settings_button']))

        {
        $form_field_1 = $_POST['form_field_1'];}
        $form_field_2 = $_POST['form_field_2'];}            
        $form_field_3 = $_POST['form_field_3'];}
        }

        ?>
```

Once I have the variables I then store them in a database.

The form works great if I just post from the form to the processor script without using the javascript however when I use the javascript nothing happens. I'm obviously doing something very wrong but can work this out at all as I cant see what is being received by the processor. Has anyone got any ideas on how i can get this to work?

It would also be great if I can return the data so that I can see what is being passed to the script as this would help me to debug any issues?

Comment: What is the `.post` inside the `.submit` supposed to do? Why do you even need it (given the `.submit` fires once the form... submits)?

Comment: Additionally, your `return false;` is stopping the form from actually submitting.

Comment: You have to solve your 'return false;' and use '$form.submit(function(e){e.preventDefault();...});' to Cancel the default action (navigation) of the click.